# Сендвич и лэптоп, но пете?

Tags: орфография

Главное правило говорит, что в словах из других языков, когда произносится *э*, мы пишем *е* после согласных, и это правило сразу же говорит про некоторые слова-исключения, в которых *э* вместо *е* пишется, а именно: *сэр, мэр, мэтр, сэндвич, пэр, лэптоп, пленэр, рэкетир.* Можно подумать, что это отступление от морфологичности обусловлено тем, что эти слова так с давних времён было писать принято. Однако там же-с есть ещё и слова, которые были и недавно заимствованы: *сэндвич, лэптоп.*

В этой связи у меня есть огромный вопрос (интересный, между прочим): почему такие исключения появляются и появляются, и кажется, они так и будут появляться? Чем это же-с, совы мудрые, обусловлено? И самое главное: когда такое новое слово появляется в языке, то мы по правилу должны его писать или всё же писать *э*, а не *е*? Я, например, не понимаю, как писать эти слова: *лэпстик* или *лепстик*, *пэте* или *пете*? (Может быть, надо *э* писать, чтобы предупредить неправильное произношение? А если я вообще новое слово хочу сделать, то мне как его делать правильно: по правилу – тогда будет *кетр* ("буйный кот") – или всё же нарушая правило главное – тогда будет *кэтр*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Мудрые совы все знают, они ответят на любой ваш вопрос…*

**Правила и исключения?** А здесь игра без правил. Все правила — это графика, выбор парных букв.
Обычно парные гласные мы выбираем по слуху: мал — мял, лук— люк, вол — вёл, мил — мыл.  Но с буквами Э/Е так не получится, у них своя история.

**1. История буквы Э**

Буква Э (так называемое «Э оборотное») – сравнительно «молодая» буква в русском алфавите: она появилась лишь в XVIII веке, вскоре после установления гражданской азбуки, при этом, по сравнению с буквой Е, она стала обозначать чистый, нейотированный звук.

Первоначальное назначение Э – употребление в начале слова или после гласных (этот, эх, поэтому), в заимствованных словах (поэт) и в иноязычных собственных именах (Эдисон, Суэц).

Несмотря на неприятие этой буквы некоторыми писателями и учеными, она не только закрепилась в русской графике, но и пишется сейчас после согласных тоже в некоторых заимствованных словах (мэр, рэп, плэнер).

В то же время буква Э так и осталась буквой с ограниченными возможностями, так как в большинстве случаев для обозначения звука Э после согласных ее заменяет буква Е.

В исконно русских словах звук Э употребляется только **после мягких согласных** и обозначается **буквой Е** (лес, мел). Твердое произношение гласного Э характерно для **заимствованных** слов, с чем и связано ограничение возможностей буквы Э.

Заимствованное  слово в языке в начальный период обычно произносится с твердым Э и как бы примеряет для себя письменную форму Э или Е. Окончательный выбор зависит от многих причин (фонетических и графических).
В некоторых случаях (не так часто) письменная форма Э закрепляется в языке (как и твердое произношение), в других – пишется только Е, а произношение гласного может меняться от твердого к мягкому. В заключение делается и этот выбор – слово окончательно вписывается в фонетическую и графическую систему языка.

Именно подобные колебания при выборе фонетической формы заимствованных слов не позволяют навести строгий порядок в написании букв Э и Е, а также в произношении соответствующих им звуков.

**2. Существует два способа заимствования слов**

**Транслитерация** — это способ заимствования, при котором заимствуется написание иностранного слова: буквы заимствуемого слова заменяются буквами родного языка.

**Транскрипция** (фонетический способ) — это такое заимствование словарной единицы, при котором сохраняется её звуковая форма (иногда несколько видоизменённая в соответствии с фонетическими особенностями языка, в который слово заимствуется).

**3. Примеры решений**

Рассмотрим слова с буквой Э: ***сэр, мэр, мэтр, сэндвич, пэр, лэптоп, пленэр, рэкетир***. Это те слова,  в которых сначала стала писаться буква Э, а потом ничего не изменилось. Для них при заимствовании обычно ориентировались на букву «а» **в английских словах**, обозначающую звук Э. В дальнейшем переход в Е не состоялся: вариант звука Э так и остался **твердым**. Произношение мягкого варианта гласного не подошло для этих слов или по благозвучности, или в связи с необходимостью различать пары слов (сер - сэр, мэр - мер и др.)

(1) ***Сэндвич*** и ***сандвич*** [англ. sandwich]. Существует несколько версий происхождения слова, все они связаны с именем графа Джона Монтегю Сэндвича четвертого, жившего в городе Сэндвиче, в XVIII веке. Граф был одним из самых знаменитых в своем роде, первым лордом адмиралтейства.

(2) **Пленэром** называют технику создания полностью готовых картин на природе при естественном освещении. Это слово произошло от французского ***en plein air***, что переводится как «на открытом воздухе». Мастера пленэрной живописи работают вне студий и стараются запечатлеть колебания цвета, которые возникают в естественной среде под воздействием погоды и солнечных лучей.

(3) **Рэкетир** [англ. racketeer < racket шум, суета; шантаж]

(4) ***Мэтр***  от  фр. мaître  (господин, хозяин; учитель).

(5) ***Лэптоп*** [англ. laptop < lap колени + top верхушка, крышка] — портативный переносной компьютер, внешне похожий на чемоданчик; его размеры несколько больше, чем у ноутбука.

(6) ***Пете***? Это русское имя, буква Е обозначает мягкий вариант гласного (выбор по слуху).

(7) ***Кэтр*** — от англ. cat.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я случайно написал *пете*, хотя имел в виду, писать ли *пате* или *патэ*. (Это слово, обозначающее в русском языке "паштет".)

Comment: pate французское по происхождению слово,  при заимствовании использован метод транслитерации. В русском языке твердое произношение гласного в конце слова на ударном слоге. И можно отметить колебания в написании слова (пате и патэ), а в орфографическом словаре РАН его еще нет. Но можно прогнозировать, что в конце концов будет утверждена буква Е.

Comment: А почему же всё же есть некая вероятность, что вместо *пате* утвердят *патэ*? Зачем в принципе новые исключения делать?

Comment: Такое решение маловероятно, уже сейчас вариант с Е встречается намного чаще. Буква Э (патэ) писалась, когда слово только появилось в языке, например: https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_culinary/1694/патэ Сейчас оно уже вполне освоилось, стало узнаваемым.

Comment: @Pumpkin777   Вы неправильно поняли. Sharon пишет: *"Но можно прогнозировать, что в конце концов будет утверждена буква **Е**".*